# Python AsyncIO, multithreading and multiprocessing performance

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I'm actually trying to speed-up a piece of code that is writing thousands of small files.
My first idea was to use asyncIO, as writing file is a blocking I/O.
I also thought it could be interesting to test mutlithreading and processing

After few tests, I am very puzzled with the results:
1°) Almost no difference between sync and async algorithm.

2°) The performances change (a lot) depending which method I call out first.

3°) multithreading and multiprocessing are so slow, even if I took care to limit the number of threads or processes

Is there something wrong with my benchmark?

Or maybe you have another much smarter idea for this kind of problem?

Thank you
Julien

```py
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
import os
import random
import shutil
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count


def compute_time(f):
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print(time.time() - start)
        return result

    return wrapped_func


def async_compute_time(f):
    async def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = await f(*args, **kwargs)
        print(time.time() - start)
        return result

    return wrapped_func


def clean_dir():
    try:
        shutil.rmtree("toto")
    except:
        pass
    os.mkdir("toto")


# =========================SYNC========================
def write_to_file(filename, content):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(content)

@compute_time
def write_sync(n):
    content = str(random.randint(0, 100))
    for i in range(n): 
        filename = f"toto/file_{i}.txt"
        write_to_file(filename, content)


# =========================ASYNC
import aiofiles


async def async_write_to_file(filename, content):
    async with aiofiles.open(filename, "w") as f:
        await f.write(content)


@async_compute_time
async def async_write_sync(n):
    MAX_CORO = 1600 #found this number to be otpimum "by hand"
    content = str(random.randint(0, 1000))

    for sub in range(0, n, MAX_CORO):
        task = []
        for i in range(sub, min(sub + MAX_CORO, n)):
            filename = f"toto/file_{i}.txt"
            task.append(async_write_to_file(filename, content))
        await asyncio.gather(*task)


# =====================Thread
@compute_time
def write_sync_multi_thread(n):
    MAX_THREAD = 8
    content = str(random.randint(0, 100))
    threads = []
    for sub in range(0, n, MAX_THREAD):
        for i in range(sub, min(sub + MAX_THREAD, n)):
            filename = f"toto/file_{i}.txt"
            t = threading.Thread(target=write_to_file, args=(filename, content))
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()
        for t in threads:
            t.join()


# Multiprocessing
@compute_time
def write_sync_multi_processing(n):
    NUMBER_OF_WORKER = 5
    content = str(random.randint(0, 100))
    processes = []
    for sub in range(0, n, 5):
        for i in range(sub, min(sub + NUMBER_OF_WORKER, n)):
            filename = f"toto/file_{i}.txt"
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=write_to_file, args=(filename, content))
            processes.append(p)
            p.start()
        for p in processes:
            p.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 10000
    # clean_dir()
    # write_sync_multi_thread(n)
    clean_dir()
    asyncio.run(async_write_sync(n))
    clean_dir()
    write_sync(n)

    # clean_dir()
    # write_sync_multi_processing(n)
```

Comment: Creating a thread or a process has an overhead. Don't do that for every single file.

Comment: You are so right. I changed it and it work much better for multihreading. But, i still don't understand why asyncio isn't muche faster than the rest...